# cygwin link generated from sdkman not recognized in windows 7

Tags: cygwin, windows-7-x64, symlink, sdkman

I am trying to use sdkman to manage versions of Groovy/etc on a Windows 7 box. All is fine when using a cygwin command prompt, but I want the Windows GROOVY_HOME set to the current. To do this, I have tried setting the CYGWIN environment variable to:

1. export CYGWIN=winsymlinks:native
2. export CYGWIN=winsymlinks

The CYGWIN doc seems to indicate that first method for defining links is appropriate, and that the second is more of a fallback. Changing the variable does indeed result in a different link - neither of which works in Windows 7.

The following is my current CYGWIN state.

```
[~]➔ echo $CYGWIN
winsymlinks
[~]➔ sdk default groovy 2.3.6

Default groovy version set to 2.3.6
[~]➔ groovy -version
Groovy Version: 2.3.6 JVM: 1.8.0_31 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 7
[~]➔ uname
CYGWIN_NT-6.1
[~]➔ uname -r
2.4.1(0.293/5/3)
```

Current Windows settings:

```
C:\Users\uc164033>echo %GROOVY_HOME%
C:\Users\uc164033\local\bin\cygwin64\home\uc164033\.sdkman\candidates\groovy\current

C:\Users\uc164033>cd %GROOVY_HOME%
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\uc164033\local\bin\cygwin64\home\uc164033\.sdkman\candidates\groovy>dir
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 7E0E-38C5

 Directory of C:\Users\uc164033\local\bin\cygwin64\home\uc164033\.sdkman\candidates\groovy

03/29/2016  10:50 AM    <DIR>          .
03/29/2016  10:50 AM    <DIR>          ..
07/28/2014  03:28 PM    <DIR>          2.3.6
07/09/2015  08:58 PM    <DIR>          2.4.4
02/18/2016  10:16 PM    <DIR>          2.4.6
03/29/2016  10:22 AM             1,285 current.lnk
               1 File(s)          1,285 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  896,974,188,544 bytes free
```

I can live with this as is, but sure would like to make my life simpler being that I cannot run on a Mac nor a Linux machine.